# How can i add an UndoableEditListener to JTable cells?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, undo-redo

Can i add an UndoableEditListener to a JTable? For example with a JTextField we do this :

```
textField = new JTextField();
      Document doc = textField.getDocument();
      doc.addUndoableEditListener(new MyUndoableEditListener());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that for `CellEditor` of the `JTabel` in next way:

use `DefaultCellEditor` with `JTextField` :

```
JTextField field = new JTextField();
field.getDocument().addUndoableEditListener(new UndoableEditListener() {

    @Override
    public void undoableEditHappened(UndoableEditEvent arg0) {
        System.out.println("profit");
    }
});
DefaultCellEditor editor = new DefaultCellEditor(field);
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(COLUMN_INDEX).setCellEditor(editor);
```

`table` is your `JTable` and `COLUMN_INDEX` index of needed column.

Answer (score 1):

No one stop use to assign this listener to the `Document` of of Text Field cell editor of `JTable` :) For your table use a custom cell editor, implement the `UndoableEditListener` to the editor's text component's Document.

Check out the Official [Tutorial page for example and demo using `CellEditor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editor)